# How to find this limit? $\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\frac{x-2x^3}{\sqrt{x^2-x^4}}$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

How to find this limit?
l'Hopital's rule doesn't seem to work here...

$$\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\frac{x-2x^3}{\sqrt{x^2-x^4}}$$

Thanks!

Comment: Factorise both the numerator and denominator to get a factor $x$, and cancel it. Be careful with the two cases $x>0$ and $x<0$.

Comment: Not sure why, but no one has pointed out the limit doesn't exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint** : $${{x-2x^3}\over\sqrt{x^2-x^4}}={{x(1-2x^2)}\over {\color{red}{|x|}\sqrt{1-x^2}}}$$. If $x>0$ you have:

$${{x-2x^3}\over\sqrt{x^2-x^4}}={{1-2x^2}\over {\sqrt{1-x^2}}}$$

and if $x<0$ you have

$${{x-2x^3}\over\sqrt{x^2-x^4}}={{2x^2-1}\over {\sqrt{1-x^2}}}$$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** Divide up and down by $x$ and you should get non-zero denominator

Answer (score 0):

1.Take x common & cancel it.

2.Rationalize by multiplying by the denominator's conjugate 
or in simple words multiply by underoot(1+x^2)/underoot(1+x^2).

3.Put value & simplfy.